Recovering Fourier series coefficients from the Fourier transform of a function extended on the unit circle.
I'm working on a problem involving Fourier transforms and functions extended on the unit circle. Given a function $f(x)$, I'm considering its extension on the unit circle and its Fourier transform.
Specifically, I have:

A function $f(x)$ defined on some domain (possibly the real line or the complex plane).
Its extension on the unit circle: $g(t) = f(e^{it})$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
The Fourier transform of $g(t)$ with respect to $t$:
$F(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(e^{it}) e^{-iwt} dt$

Note that $g(t)$ is $2\pi$-periodic by construction. Consequently, $F(w)$ is a distribution with poles at $w = 2\pi n$ for integer $n$.
My question is: How can we recover the Fourier series coefficients of $g(t)$, given by
$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) e^{-int} dt$
using only the known Fourier transform $F(w)$?
I understand that this likely involves analyzing the behavior of $F(w)$ near its poles and possibly using distribution theory or residue calculus, but I'm not sure how to proceed rigorously.
Some specific questions:

How does the periodicity of $g(t)$ manifest in the structure of $F(w)$?
Can we express $c_n$ as a limit involving $F(w)$ as $w$ approaches $2\pi n$?
Is there a general formula relating $F(w)$ to the sequence $\{c_n\}$?

Any insights, formal derivations, or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated!

The Fourier transform is a sum of Dirac deltas $\sum c_n \delta(w - n)$, so the Fourier coefficients are just the coefficients of this sum.
